# Exit with non-zero code cURL command yields 404 etc

Tags: curl

When curl gets a status code of certain values, how to exit with non-zero?

I have this script:

```
 set -e;

 mkdir -p "${dir}";

 cd "${dir}";

 curl -O https://bitbucket.org/interos/${repo}/get/${commit}.tar.gz

 tar -xvzf ${commit}.tar.gz
```

even though the curl command corresponds to an http response with a 404, still exits with 0, so my script continues even tho I don't want it to ... what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
curl -s -w %{http_code} -O https://bitbucket.org/interos/${repo}/get/${commit}.tar.gz | grep -q 200
```

You can adjust `grep` to match the desired response codes.